# How to manipulate variable scope?

Tags: javascript, lexical-scope, dynamic-scope

Learning some TypeScript. 
Trying to make this bit of code work:

```
...
ocrText: string;
...
foo() {
    Tesseract.recognize(<Tesseract.ImageLike>document.getElementById('image'))
       .then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            this.ocrText = result.text;
       });
}
```

Getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'ocrText' of undefined`

The console log does show the object properties and values.

How do I extract the local value of the 'text' property from the 'result' object to a global scope?

Comment: re-tagged as this has nothing to do with TypeScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `window` instead of `this`:

```
var Text = '';
(()=> fetch('www.example.com')
 .then(response => response.text())
 .then(text => window.Text=text))();
```

Don't know too much about typescript, but I'm guessing that it's using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), where `this` is undefined instead of defaulting to the global `window` object if not used in the context of a class instance.

Comment: By the by this assumes top-level declaration of the variable and function; if you're not working in the global scope just omit `window.` and it will refer to whatever enclosing scope you're in.